# Self-catering in Scandinavia

Tags: food-and-drink, scandinavia, nordic-countries

I'm planning a driving trip from Copenhagen to Norway. I understand that Scandinavia is expensive. If I want to rely on self-catering as much as possible, how much should I budget daily for food for two adults? (I suppose a sub-question is, how much will costs vary as I cross from Denmark to Sweden to Norway?)

### Edit:

We're talking about fairly simple stuff like bread, cheese, produce, and coffee.

Comment: I would imagine that the kind of food you're planning on eating would have a significant effect on what you're spending, so you may want to include that information. (If you buy a loaf of bread and a chunk of cheese and eat that for a week, it would cost much less than expecting meat or fresh seafood every day.)

Comment: From Copenhagen to the Norwegian border is only like 5hrs. Costs may vary a bit (Sweden cheapest I think), but they don't differ that much from the rest of Western Europe. Crossing the Öresund bridge costs 50 EUR for a normal car, which is currently 515 SEK. [ICA](https://www.ica.se/handla-online/ica-matkassen/) seem to think 25 SEK/day/person is normal for groceries.

Comment: The ICA combos @TomasBy links to appear to be designed to cover dinner only. And for a whole family too; one should expect more overhead when buying for only two persons. In Denmark at least, you wouldn't be able to come up with a very exciting dinner for two for 50 kr.

Comment: No, I guess 50 SEK/day would be a lower limit.